# Mysql statement should leave a maximum of 3 rows per account but instead, it deletes ALL the rows and just leaves 3 of the latest rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I guess my question is somewhat vague but I'm gonna explain it further.

**What should happen:** Let's say a user named `John` made 2 comments while already having 3 comments named after him on the database. What `$sql2` should do is to select all comments made by `John`, order them by their `comment_id` and delete all comments by `John` except for the last 3 comments by `John`.

---

**I have this code:**

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO comments(comment,name) VALUES ('$comment','$name')";
mysqli_query($con,$sql1);

$sql2 = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE comment_id NOT IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT comment_id FROM comments ORDER BY comment_id desc LIMIT 3) s)";
mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
```

**What happens:** It deletes **ALL** of the rows and just leaves the top three rows regardless of their names

---

**I have tried another code:**

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO comments(comment,name) VALUES ('$comment','$name')";
mysqli_query($con,$sql1);

$sql2 = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT name FROM comments ORDER BY comment_id desc LIMIT 3) s)";
mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
```

**What happens:** It **ONLY** accepts 1 user, if I tried putting `Scot` as the name, it deletes everything except `Scot` in the table, and it doesn't even get limited to 3

Comment: Please, this is just me practicing on how to manipulate the database, this is for educational purposes, I have no intention to use this online. And besides, what makes you so sure that I haven't made this line, $comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$rawcomment);

Comment: In your first try just add `AND user = 'John'` in the end of the statement. Also please read about [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Furthermore I would recommend using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of mysqli since PDO can actually do prepared statements.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work since basically the delete statement is deleting everything that was not part of the group, so if `Scot` tries to insert, the delete will also initiate deleting `John's` records as well as any other one since at the time of deletion, it was stated that it will keep `Scot's` top three records and just delete everything.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is basically saying that it should delete all rows which do not match the subquery. Since your subquery is pulling in the 3 rows you want to keep, the where clause will then delete everything not matching the 3 returned via your subquery.

A much more efficient query would be to do a delete where id is in the list of rows you do wish to remove.